# How to fix "ask on a date" phone bug?

Tags: the-sims-4

My previous Sim went on a date with no problems. I didn't update the game since then.

My current Sim is unable to arrange dates by any means! When I use the phone button he puts the cellphone but the task is immediatly dismissed. The option is not available in the social interactions either, even though the romance level is maxed out.

How do I fix this issue? Mod fixes are also welcome.

**More details:**

- It's not a mod issue. I've already tried "ask on a date" with a clean game.

Comment: Just curious, since the question has been asked, has this issue been fixed for you?

Comment: I don't remember. It's been a while I don't play that game.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar bug with not able to cook with fridge. What I ended up doing was repair the game (right click on Sims 4 title in the library and click "repair"), and it works fine for me.

I'm not sure if this will help your issue specifically, but I suppose it's worth a try.